# How can I enable trace output in NUnit 3's Visual Studio adapter?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nunit, nunit-3.0

Consider:

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    Trace.TraceInformation("Hello");
}
```

When running it from Visual Studio 2015, the output window (Tests) shows no trace lines:

```
------ Discover test started ------
NUnit Adapter 3.4.0.0: Test discovery starting
NUnit Adapter 3.4.0.0: Test discovery complete
========== Discover test finished: 9 found (0:00:01.325888) ==========
------ Run test started ------
NUnit Adapter 3.4.0.0: Test execution started
Running selected tests in C:\Projects\bla-bla.dll
NUnit3TestExecutor converted 9 of 9 NUnit test cases
NUnit Adapter 3.4.0.0: Test execution complete
========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:03.5445181) ==========
```

I remember it was working fine with NUnit 2 and Visual Studio 2013. Do I need to somehow turn it on?

My `app.config` has no overrides to default `<system.diagnostics>`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [this discussion](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1139), they removed that because of technical reasons.

An alternative solution might be something like this:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

    namespace MyUnitTest {
        [TestFixture]
        public class UnitTest1 {
            [Test()]
            public void Test1() {
                var x = "Before Test";
                TestContext.Progress.WriteLine(x);
                x = "Hello";
                TestContext.Progress.WriteLine(x);
                Assert.IsTrue(x == "Hello");
                x = "After Test";
                TestContext.Progress.WriteLine(x);
            }
        }
    }
```

With the given result:

> NUnit Adapter 3.4.1.0: Test execution started Running selected tests
> in C:\ProjectPath\MyUnitTest.dll NUnit3TestExecutor converted 1 of 1
> NUnit test cases Before Test Hello After Test NUnit Adapter 3.4.1.0:
> Test execution complete
> ========== Test execution complete: 1 run(0:00:00,7660762) ==========

#### Conclusion

You can't use `Trace` anymore on outputs for NUnit.

Comment: Is this line normal - "NUnit3TestExecutor converted 9 of 9 NUnit test cases"? It sort of looks like it is doing extra work every time, why are they "converted"?

Comment: I think that's because NUnit and VS test interfaces are different so NUnit VS adapter has to "convert" its tests so that VS understands them.

Comment: "You cant use Trace anymore on outputs for NUnit" well it is possible to register a listener and redirect the information to whatever sink

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** You can use the output window to review trace information

**Option 2:** In your startup, add a TextWriterTraceListener